# Should I use Exceptions while parsing complex user input

Tags: parsing, exception, architecture

when looking for Information when and why to use Exceptions there are many people (also on this platform) making the point of not using exceptions when validating user-input because invalid input is not an exceptional thing to happen.

I now have the case where I have to parse a complex string of user input and map it to an Object-Tree basically, similar to a Parser.

Example in pseudo code:

```
input:
----
hello[5]
+
foo["ok"]
----

results in something like that:
class Hello {
  int id = 5
}

class Add {}

class foo {
  string name = 'ok'
}
```

Now in order to "validate" that input I have to parse it, having code that parses the input for validation and code to create the objects separately feels redundant.

Currently I'm using Exceptions while parsing single tokens to collect all Errors.

```
// one token is basically a single
try {
  foreach (token in tokens) {
    factory = getFactory(token) // throws ParseException
    addObject(factory.create(token)) // throws ParseException
  }
} catch (ParseException e) {
  // e.g. "Foo Token expects value to be string"
  addError(e)
}
```

is this bad use of exceptions?
An alternative would be to inject a validation class in every factory or mess around with return types (feels a bit dirty)

Answer (score 0):

If exceptions work for your use case, go for it.

The usual problem with exceptions is that they don't let you fix things up and continue, which makes it hard to implement parser error recovery. You can't really fix up a bad input, and you probably shouldn't even in cases where you could, but error recovery lets you report more than one error from the same input, which is often considered convenient.

All of that depends on your needs and parsing strategy, so there's not a lot of information to go on here.